# How to train and read the particular text from Image/PDF?

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, pdftotext, read-text, image-text

Image or PDF may contains

**

1. Printed text,
2. Handwritten text,
3. Paragraphs,
4. Key value pairs,
5. Complex Tables.

**

While training, we will assign the tags/keywords for the document. When testing will look for the tag and read the result for the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 steps:

1. First of all you should write basic object recognition algorithm for
   an image. The algorithm must crop your image to the ROIs (regions of
   interests), then it should classify each ROI by elements from your
   content type list. For this part you can use some heuristics rules
   (tables, for example, sometimes has a rectangle boundaries) to get
   ROIs features. Then you may use a lightweight classifier like a
   decision tree.
2. Next you should provide algorithm for reading your data structure
   defined by a ROI type. For example, for table you should find all
   cells at the image. Then you need to find each word or number from
   your data structure and crop it to the symbols sets.
3. When you have do it, you will have to classify each symbol by your
   text-image classifier. On this step, you can use a Multilayer
   Perceptron for example or Bayesian Naive Classifier, and another
   type of classifiers which usually used for image recognition.

In the practice, you could try [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) library, which already has almost all algorithms you need to do your stuff.

For better understanding of 3rd step you could watch [my project](https://github.com/egorrrrrrrrr/cap2char) for captcha recognizing based on OpenCV Artificial Neural Network feature usage.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response. Is there any Cognitive Services to do the same task?

Comment: https://www.onlineocr.net/ for example, or most popular https://finereaderonline.com

Comment: I would like to create the trained model first, then read the specific text that might be available as key value pair or inside the table or sentence from a paragraph

Comment: Your task is quite bit specific, I don't sure that somewhere there is a ready solution for it.

Comment: Your "my project" seems to be no longer available.

Comment: Now is available, just try again to click the link.